# Can't hear generated sine waves of durations shorter than 100ms in Android

Tags: android, audio, sample, audiotrack

I put together the code below to generate and play sine wave sounds on Android devices.

numSamples determines the length of the sound based on the sampling frequency (44.1KHz). So, if I for instance set numSamples = 22500, the sound will play for 500ms.

While the code works fine for long sound duration (i.e. longer than 150ms), I can't hear any sound if I set numSamples to achieve shorter play duration. For instance, if I set numSamples to 3000, I don't hear anything.

How can I adjust my code, so that I can play sinus-wave sounds on my Android device with very short duration, e.g. 1ms, 10ms, 50ms, 100ms?

Please kindly advise.

```
void playSound(double freqOfTone, int numSamples) {
    final int sampleRate = 44100;

    final double sample[] = new double[numSamples];
    final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];

    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate / freqOfTone));
    }

    // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
    // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
    int idx = 0;
    for (double dVal : sample) {
        short val = (short) (dVal * 32767);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }

    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            numSamples,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, numSamples);
    audioTrack.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested with headphones? Laptop speakers and even more so tablets, phone, hand-helds often have speakers that are really bad at playing low tones. With a good pair of headphones you should be able to hear lower pitches. I'd test that before getting into the weeds with the algorithm (which on the surface looks ok).

PS might want to edit "sinus" to "sine".